# Is there a way to list sub properties in sparql?

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, rdfs

I have such a requirement. Some resources like `Person` have properties like `dateOfBirth` and `dateOfDeath`. Some resources like `Event` have properties like `startsDate` and `endsDate`. In addition, I know these date related properties are subproperties of `Date`. How can I list all the resources having a subproperty of `Date`? Or How can I list all the subproperties of `Date` in *sparql*?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Obviously, `rdfs:subPropertyOf` is the relationship between those properties, thus, you have to use a triple pattern with it

Answer (score 2):

I take it that `Date` is a property so I'll use a lowercase first letter:

```
SELECT ?subprop
WHERE {
   ?subprop rdfs:subPropertyOf :date .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're after, might try something like this:

```
select distinct ?predicate where {
  :Date ?predicate ?object .
}
```

or

```
select ?predicate, ?object where {
  :Date ?predicate ?object .
}
```